# Predicting changes in pH of water when chlorinating using two different methods

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, ph, water-treatment

Two methods for chlorinating water are using chlorine gas $(\ce{Cl2})$ or calcium hypochlorite $(\ce{Ca(OCl)2}).$ By using chemical equations how can you predict the pH of the water brought about by the chlorinating process?

Answer (score 3):

1. In aqueous solution, chlorine can undergo disproportionation: one atom in $\ce{Cl2}$ (oxidation state $0$) is reduced to $\ce{Cl-}$ (oxidation state $-1),$ the other is oxidized to a species in which the chlorine atom has the oxidation state $+1.$

   > $$\ce{Cl2 + 3H2O -> 2H3O+ + Cl- + OCl-}$$

   Ask yourself how that influences the pH of the solution.
2. What about adding calcium hypochlorite to water? If $\ce{CaCl2}$ is the calcium salt of hydrochloric acid, what about $\ce{Ca(OCl)2}?$

   > You may have guessed it: $\ce{Ca(OCl)2}$ is the calcium salt of chloric(I) acid.

   You may remember that adding the soluble salt $\ce{MA}$ of a strong acid $\ce{HA}$ to water will not influence the pH of the solution.

   > If $\ce{HA}$ is a *strong acid*, it will *fully dissociate* in water:
   >  $$\ce{HA + H2O <=>> A- + H3O+}$$
   >  This means in return that the *corresponding base* $\ce{A-}$ is *very weak*:
   >  $$\ce{A- + H2O <<=> HA +OH-}$$

   Now, is $\ce{OCl-}$ a strong or a weak base? In order to decide, you might want to have a look up the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of the corresponding acid and keep in mind that for a corresponding acid-base pair in water $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} = 14.$